# Storing a Binary Value into an unsigned int array

Tags: c, arrays, binary, unsigned-integer

I've been having some trouble storing a binary value into an `unsigned int` array. I was trying to pass through the binary representation as a `char` array however it's not working as I had hoped. What I was doing was going through the `char` array using a `while` loop and assigning each number to an element to the `unsigned int` array but that is completely wrong. I just pretty much want to know how to store a binary value into an `unsigned int`. How do I show zeros in front? I've tried putting in the array just the binary value without `0`s at the front but that wasn't working. Could I convert the binary to `int` value and then convert it back at print time?

Here is the basic code for the function

```
void setstring(unsigned int array[10], char *bitString) {
    len=strlen(bitString);
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        for (int p=1; d%32!=0; d++) {
             array[10-i]=bitString[len-];
        }
    }
}
```

The printing is just meant to print the `bitString` or the array but at the moment nothing is printing at all. The print is simply a `for` loop which iterates through the `unsigned int` array.

Comment: What do you mean by 'binary'? True/false, or some sort of bit-mask? Perhaps it's easier if you show a relevant code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean as in a 32 bit string of 1's and 0's. I'm trying to store in an unsigned int. I would try to put it my code but I think it's completely wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and give a minimal example including observed and expected output.

Comment: You want to turn a decimal number to binary and save it as decimal ? Why ?

Comment: @danielwestfall post your code even if it's wrong. That way we would be able to answer __your__ question instead of guessing what you meant

Comment: @TonyTannous I was thinking about turning a binary to a decimal and saving it in the array and printing it out as binary.

Comment: If the binary string is less than or equal to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned)` I think that it is not necessary to use an array. Use simply `strtoul` for store.

Comment: `array[10-i]=bitString[len-p);` is certainly not true compilable code: `)` vs `]`.  What else is not true code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your (set) of functions :

```
int binary_string_to_integer(const char *str, unsigned int *vl)
{
    unsigned int value = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if (str == NULL || vl == NULL || !strlen(str)) result = -1;
    if (!result)
    {
        while (!result && *str)
        {
            if (*str != '1' && *str != '0')
            {
                result = -1;
            }
            value <<= 1;
            value += (*str++ == '1');
        }
    }
    if (!result) *vl = value;
    return result;
}
```

---

```
int binary_string_to_integer_array_of_0_or_1(const char *str, int *vl, int skipzeroes)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (str == NULL || vl == NULL || !strlen(str)) result = -1;
    if (!result)
    {
        while (*str)
        {
            if (*str != '1' && *str != '0')
            {
                result = -1;
                break;
            }
            if (skipzeroes && !result && *str == '0')
            {
                str++;
                continue;
            }
            *(vl + result++) = (*str++ == '1');
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char tmp;
    size_t len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(str + i);
            *(str + i) = *(str + len - i - 1);
            *(str + len - i - 1) = tmp;

        }
    }
    return str;
}

char *uint_to_binary_string(unsigned int vl, char *buff)
{
    char *ptr = buff;

    if (buff != NULL)
    {
        while (vl)
        {
            *ptr++ = '0' + (vl & 1);
            vl >>= 1;
        }
    }
    *ptr = 0;
    return reverse(buff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a function to set particular bits of an `unsigned char` variable.

Try using this to set bits

```
void setBit(unsigned char *target, int pos)
{
    //pos must be < sizeof(unsigned char)
    unsigned char mask=1<<pos;
    *target = *target | mask;
}
```

And this to unset bits

```
void unsetBit(unsigned char *target, int pos)
{
    unsigned char mask=~(1<<pos);
    *target = *target & mask;
}
```

Note that `pos` begins from `0`.

You could use these functions for displaying the bits:

```
int getBit(unsigned char target, int pos)
{
    target = target>>pos;
    return target & 1;

}

void printBits(unsigned char target)
{
    int i;
    for(i=sizeof(target)*8-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        printf("%d", getBit(target, i));
    }
}
```

In these functions the target variable is passed by reference.

Example:

```
unsigned char a=0;
setBit(&a, 0);
setBit(&a, 1);
setBit(&a, 6);
printf("\nBit pattern is: ");
printBits(a);
printf(". Value is %d.", a);
```

would print

```
Bit pattern is: 01000011. Value is 67.
```

Further

```
unsetBit(&a, 1);
printf("\nBit pattern is: ");
printBits(a);
printf(". Value is %d.", a);
```

would give

```
Bit pattern is: 01000001. Value is 65.
```

EDIT: [This](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html) is a good place to learn bit manipulation.